# woocommerce: display_price_suffix with condition

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to show Woo commerce field `price display suffix` to '+tax' only for the country code i put in the Standard Tax. I don't want other users all over globe to see that suffix as they don't have to pay tax.

I tried to use 'Price based on country'plugin but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far. This will help us help you.

Comment: Hi @kilojoules....I was trying this code but not sure, how to test country code specifically for Tax->standard Tax . This code makes '+TAX' display for every country : 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
    if ($country_code='US')
 {$price = $price . '+tax' ;
            return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );}
}

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_suffix', 100, 2 );

function custom_price_suffix( $price, $product ){
    if ($country_code='US')
 {$price = $price . '+tax' ;
            return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );}
}

Comment: Like, put that in your question. Try to make it a self-contained document that is a fun challenge and a good read. So far, this seems like you've put in very little effort. We're all volunteers.

Comment: @Kilojoules..thanks for pushing me....i understood.. that the problem is not that easy for anyone!! i was expecting this to be simple ... i thought someone would through away country_code variable like that... i am trying new stuff...will post if got through it...